# How to copy data from one sheet to another based on matching criteria

Tags: vba, excel

Source data:
[image: Source Data]

Target:
[image: Target]

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I need to copy data from a source file to a target file based on a column in the target file being an exact match to values in a column from the source file.

Based on the attached image, Coverage Pattern Name exists in both files. I need to copy the coverage term data over but the issue is there may be multiple coverage term values for the same type of coverage pattern name. I need to bring in all unique coverage terms.

Essentially, if coverage description from (Target file) exists as coverage pattern name (from source file), then I need to populate covtermpattern (in target file) from coverageterm (from source file).

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it is certainly possible.  If you get stuck at any point, please let us know what isn't working and we can help you to get it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the vlookup function.
If I get you right and assuming that:

1. Both sheets are in the same file;
2. Target is a sheet named "target", and Source is a sheet named "source";
3. That "Coverage description" column is column source!A, then

in the cells of "target!covtermpattern write something like:

```
=ifna(vlookup(A2,source!K:K,1,FALSE), "---")
```

Explained

**= ifna()** will return the value of the first instruction unless it is an error. I.e, there is no match on Source from Target. In that case, it will return the character "---". You can later filter them.

**vlookup()** is the function to import the values of a certain row, given a match of two values.
A2 points to the value we are looking for in vertically in a column (or subset) that we specify in the following instruction.

**source!K:K** represents the abovementioned search space: the whole column K from sheet "source".

**1** represents how many spaces to the right of the match is the value we are looking for. 1 represents the very column specified (K). 2 would lead you to column N. 3 to M [...]

**FALSE** lets you retrieve approximate values. It only works on numerical matches, though.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi Nicolas, I appreciate your response. I had actually initially tried to use a vlookup function to obtain what I needed but I came across an issue. If we look at the source file, we can see that there are multiple same entries in the coverage pattern name (column K) due to there being multiple unique entries in coverageterm (column N). In the target file, I have coverage description which would map with coverage pattern name from the source. However vlookup only brings the first coverageterm and I would need all possible coverage terms for that coverage pattern name. Any thoughts?

Comment: =VLOOKUP( B37,source!$J:$M,4,FALSE)
This was what I initially had used. I understand why you'd have an isna, in order to filter out the ones that don't return a value I suppose. However I don't think this will help obtain all unique records (in column N) that are mapped with column K. Does that make sense?

Comment: This one would be much easier to solve in R , and less so, in VBA.
You have  problem that requires pivoting data from long to wide formats.
Yet, one dirty way of doing it in basic Excel is to concatenate sorce's K and N values, separated by an easily identified string that never occurs in your data (I.e "§", so you can first  obtain  a list of unique K§N pairs  (i.e. through a pivot table), and alter, parse each pair into its K and N components (i.e. retrieving everything left of the "§" to reclaim K, and everything right of the "§" to reclaim N.